# Component is not showing changes after render in React Native

Tags: react-native, redux, react-native-navigation

Newbie to React Native here. I am trying to use Redux for the mobile app for React Native. There are couple of components (app screens). I am choosing the item from one screen (has list of items) and provide it to the next one as param to show its details. When I do it first time, everything is correct. But if I choose another item in the list screen, the second screen does not show the correct item details. Instead it shows the details for the previously selected item.

First screen provides the item and navigates:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('DetailsScreen', { item: item.value } );
```

Second screen:

```
class DetailsScreen extends Component{
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this._item = this.props.navigation.getParam(‘item’);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.dispatchData(this._item);
  }


  render(){
    return (
      <View>
        <SectionList
          sections={this.props.layout}
          stickySectionHeadersEnabled={false}
          renderItem={({item}) => (
              <ListItem
                title={item.title}
              />
          )}
          renderSectionHeader=
          {
            ({section}) => (
            <ListItem
                bottomDivider={true}
              />)
          }
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}


const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    layout: state.detailsReducer.layout,
  };
};



  const mapDispatchToProps = {
    dispatchData:  (item) => getLayout(item)
  }

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps,
)(DetailsScreen);
```

The odd thing is that I can see from the logs that new layout (from the newly selected item) is rendered, meaning the `render()` function in DetailsScreen is called with the correct up-to-date data. But I can not see those changes on the screen. What am I missing? Is this because of navigation saves the previous instance of the screen? Or something else?

Answer (score 0):

> Is this because of navigation saves the previous instance of the screen? Or something else?

answer is yes, react navigation, what it does is if you do `navigation.navigate('home')` to a page , then for the first time it renders it with every lifecycle method, but the second. time it doesnt call `componentDidMount` since it has been taken from navigation stack. What you can do is try using

```
this.props.navigation.push('DetailsScreen', { item: item.value } );
```

It will push the screen to top of stack every time its called.

Hope it helps feel free for doubts

Comment: Ok, I have tried push, and it does not help. Moreover, componentDidMount() is called  every time even when I am using navigate.

Comment: means? what exactly do you want then?

Comment: I want the screen to render the correct data. The function render() with the correct details is called according to logs. But it isn't shown on the screen. Almost like render() does not change the look of the component.

Answer (score 0):

```js
componentDidMount(){
    navigation.addListener("willFocus", () => {
  // write what you want to be rendered in here

      });
}
```